# How to Write a Simple Recursive Double Loop in Haskell Without Map or List Comprehensions

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursion so I thought I'd write a simple double for-loop with just raw Haskell (no list comprehensions, no map, etc.).

Given i and j produce the following ..

```
rTest01 2 5

[[2,5],[2,4],[2,3],[2,2],[2,1],[1,5],[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1]]
```

My code works but it doesn't seem beautiful .. I had to add
an additional argument to reload the 'j' every time 'i' changes.

Is there a cleaner way to write it?

```
rTest01 :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
rTest01 i j =
      [[i,j]] ++ rTest01' j i (j-1)

rTest01' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
rTest01' origJ i 0 = rTest01' origJ (i-1) origJ
rTest01' _ 0 _ = []
rTest01' origJ i j  =
    [[i,j]] ++ rTest01' origJ i (j-1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "raw Haskell"?  List comprehensions and higher order functions (e.g. map) are pretty core Haskell features.

Comment: I didn't know how else to say it. My friend who wanted me to write some recursive code (to compare with Java) considered using things like 'map' etc 'Cheating'

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `map` or `filter`, then your friend had better not use `java.util.*` or any other standard library features in his version.

Comment: Good point. I don't think he used it. He wants me to eventually write an 'm choose k' from 'scratch'  to compare with his two class version in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for internal recursion. In the same way that, in Python or Java, we might have a private recursive function that's only called by a public non-recursive function (where the latter doesn't take the extra "helper" arguments), we can do the same thing in Haskell using nested scopes.

```
example :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
example iorig jorig = go iorig jorig
    where go 0 _ = []
          go i 0 = go (i - 1) jorig
          go i j = (i, j) : go i (j - 1)
```

While I definitely appreciate your practice with recursion, and I do emphasize that it is a *very* good exercise to write code like this, as it practices many basic skills necessary for more complex Haskell coding, do remember that, even when written the way I have above, this is not idiomatic Haskell. If I was writing this function in production, I'd write

```
example :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
example i j = reverse $ (,) <$> [1..i] <*> [1..j]
```

(Removing the `reverse` if we don't care about the order)

Recursion is a very handy skill to have, but it's not always the solution. And indeed, in Haskell, there are often several other abstractions we can build upon to make our code simpler, such as applicatives and monads in the above example.

Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: I appreciate both an improved solution and the idiomatic solution. You have totally answered my question! Thanks

Comment: If you're going to allow yourself a `reverse`, then `reverse $ range ((1,1), (i, j))` would be my go-to. But given how laziness and GC works, avoiding `reverse` is much better; this can be done with, for example, `example i j = [(a, b) | a <- [i, i-1 ..1], b <- [j, j-1 .. 1]]`.

Comment: I spent some time trying to figure out  `example i j = reverse $ (,) <$> [1..i] <*> [1..j] ` . I sort of understand  `fmap (,) [1..2] <*> [1..5]` but there's 'looping' going on which makes me think that we're in list Monad space. I tried exploring all the types in GHCI without joy. Newbie question -- Since list has many instances how can I tell which one it's using? I know this is a basic question but I'm hoping for a Eureka moment .. :-)

Comment: Actually, the code you wrote there with `fmap` is identical to my own. `<$>` is defined to be `fmap`. And you're right that we're using the list monad. Strictly speaking, we're using the list's `Applicative` instance (which is where `<*>` is defined), but every monad is an applicative functor in a compatible way, so it's still conceptually the monadic behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response .. I guess I didn't dig deep enough before. Looking up the code for `<*>` on lists .. `fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]` .. A thinly veiled list comprehension? So it's Monadic behavior as you say but we're not using proper Monads ? I've been writing Haskell for years for computer architecture and robotic simulations and AI and I still feel like a newbie :-(

Comment: The list monad as a whole is a thinly veiled list comprehension. The definition of the monadic bind operator is `xs >>= f = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]`. It's just a different way of thinking about the problem that becomes more natural the more you use it.

Comment: @TomP Re: "Since list has many instances how can I tell which one it's using?", the answer is you look at the types of the functions you're calling. In this case [`<$>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) has type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, and [`<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) has type `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so those are the instances you're using.